# OCMock 3 not matching the string argument

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ocmock

I'm starting to use OCMock (3.1.2) in my project for unit tests, and I'm having a weird behaviour. See the following test:

```
- (void)testOCMock
{
    OCMExpect([self.delegate openEmailComposer:@"me@email.com"]);

    [self.delegate openEmailComposer:@"hello there"];
}
```

Surprisingly, the test succeeds. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you are expecting was strict (or fail-fast) mode. In your example, were you expecting the mock to complain that `openEmailComposer:` with a `@"hello there"` argument was unexpected? In that case use a strict mock.

Normally the focus is on methods that should be called. The simple failure case is something like this:

```
OCMExpect([self.delegate openEmailComposer:@"me@email.com"]);
[self.delegate openEmailComposer:@"hello there"];
OCMVerifyAll(); // fails because openEmailComposer: wasn't called with the right argument
```

Last but not least, I would suggest to use the newer verify-after-running approach:

```
[self.delegate openEmailComposer:@"hello there"];
OCMVerify([self.delegate openEmailComposer:@"me@email.com"]); // fails
```

Comment: Indeed, I was missing the `OCMVerifyAll()`; Thanks!